# Is there a way to fix missing files of laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Some guy made a site with laravel 5.6 and we at a different place need to change just some tags and the CSS, I have a git of the site but "vendor, .env" and many files that are also missing in the git, how can I open the site in my computer to adjust the style sheets I have no database backup and also installed laravel 5.6 and try to paste de missing files but there are still many errors.

Comment: `.env` and `vendor` MUST be present, even in production, or laravel won't start. If you mean `node_modules` or similar, you can restore them if you have a `package.json`. For frontend sources, if you minified them and lost original files the only thing you can do is try to revert git history to a previous commit and to hope

Comment: Thanks for the time well they are not there I was reading this was due to the gitignore file? I'm just starting with laravel and all we have is this git file so basically I can't do anything with it unless they provide me a full copy of the site?

Comment: If they have been added to `.gitignore` there's no way to recover them and yes, you have to get the full project to edit sources

Comment: thanks I was afraid of this, thank you very much I know the question perhaps reflects ignorance but yes I know very little of laravel

Comment: If you only have the git repo then there is likely no .env file as the .env will change depending on the environment and is installed when repo added to server. There are also other files that are most likely constructed on the server, like the composer and npm/yarn files, you should be able to reconstruct those in your testing environment by using composer install and npm install.  The only way to get the .env settings though will be to have access to the server. But the settings in this file probably wouldn't transfer as its normally environment settings like DB connection and logging.

Comment: @ColinMD yes actually I did that made some installs from composer for missing stuff and it worked but I still had many errors from the database, I basically wanted to know if I was making something wrong here but it seems that it's very complicated to do it in such way I can't even see the tables at the database files in database folder, I'll assume there are more missing files in the git

Answer (score 0):

Altough the original programmers excluded some files in the git repo using the ignoregit file I created a new laravel 5.6 project and copied the missing files to my original app folder, imported the missing packages using composer and finally used artisan to migrate the database using "php artisan migrate"